# I am using header(Refresh:0) and Page loads twice after using this

Tags: php, header, page-refresh

I am using `header("Refresh:0");` to redirect on the same page after login and it is working fine as i want to load it on same page but the problem is it is loading twice. I don't know why it is doing and i am not able to find any solution till now.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll take care of this in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop execution of your script, if you do not need any parts of PHP after/behind the `header()`.

```
header("Refresh:0");
exit;
```